# Do electric gloves degrade in voltage protection over time?

Tags: equipment

I am looking to buy a pair of electric gloves for PPE (Personal Protective Equipment). However I just found out that their voltage protection doesn't stay constant.

> Do these gloves need to be tested?
>
> Electrical gloves need to be tested twice a year to ensure they are
> protecting you against low, medium and high voltages. Ensure to check
> the stamped dates on the gloves.

See: https://ph.rs-online.com/web/p/work-gloves/9182243/?cm_mmc=PH-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-PLA_PH_EN_Catch_All-_-Fusion-_-9182243&matchtype=&pla-366797395360&gclid=Cj0KCQiA0rSABhDlARIsAJtjfCeAEA2t1M_xQ1YxxcZRQssqx1iuW2rQyBDikEdoiqP6hg0WVwhNaOYaAovEEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Is there a formula to calculate the drop in voltage protection of these voltage gloves over time (through not using them)? Or is it just a general guideline to have electric gloves be tested twice a year? How long do these electric gloves generally last?

Does the drop in voltage protection that they offer become greater through use?

I would like to know this information so I know how often I should be replacing these electric gloves. My mains at my area is 220V so those gloves should fit the bill.

Comment: They shouldn't degrade if just being stored. But mechanical wear and tear through use will degrade them as well as exposure to high electric fields.

Comment: Hmm yes i was wondering if their voltage protection degrades over time even through just storing them, but good to know. They should last for a lifetime, I only plan to use them for occasional housework (i.e. replace circuit breakers)

Comment: Don't forget getting them dirty.  They may require special cleaning procedures if they can be cleaned at all depending on what you do with them.

Comment: The manufacturers of the gloves will probably be happy to tell you the capabilities and storage/maintenance requirements if you contact them.  How the material performs over time and in variable humidity/sunlight/temperature etc. will depend on the material they chose.  It is a legitimate potential concern though.

Comment: If there was a teliable formula then the testing regime might have been different. Or perhaps the testing regime is the result of a formula used by the manufacturer. Test and be safe. but I never used gloves just **very** good practice.

Comment: do you really need such gloves for 220v? I think regular latex exam gloves protect against such low voltages...